# Java 7 issue - Type-ahead keystrokes are not being enqueued

Tags: java, swing, keystroke, type-ahead

I'm having an issue where keystrokes are getting lost instead of being queued up and processed when a text field gains focus. This used to work correctly in Java 6, but is no longer working correctly in Java 7.

Here is the scenario:

1. User opens a dialog that has a textfield in focus
2. Just before the dialog comes up, user starts typing something
3. Once the dialog is up and textfield has focus:
   Java 6: Anything that the user had previously typed appears in the textfield
   Java 7: Nothing appears in the textfield

Any ideas why this is happening?

Using the sample code below:
When you click on the button, the other dialog will take 4 seconds to load. In that time, start pressing some alphabumeric keys on your keyboard. Once the second dialog comes up, you will see your key presses in the textfield. This works for Java6, but not for Java7.

```
public class UITest{

public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    final UITest example = new UITest();
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            example.createMainDialog();
        }
    });
  }

  public void createMainDialog()
  {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Main Dialog");
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    JButton button = new JButton("Click Me");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {         
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            createOtherDialog();
        }
    });
    frame.add(button);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  public void createOtherDialog()
  {

    //I know this is bad to do in the EDT, but just trying to simulate a busy EDT
    try {
        Thread.sleep(4000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Other Dialog");
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    JTextField field = new JTextField(25);
    frame.add(field);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

     //Text field has focus
    field.requestFocus();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you create a small program that reproduces your problem for us, an [sscce](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: I just posted it now.

Comment: *Any ideas why this is happening?* My first thought is the dialog takes too long to be visible. I mean the first question to be answered would be "Why does the user have time enough to type something before the dialog becomes visible"? As first step I would check why this is happening. Maybe some heavy task in the EDT during the dialog creation (as you try to emulate in your SSCCE) could be done in a separate thread. Swing should be lightweight enough to show a dialog almost immediately.